# KUBERNETES AWSElasticBlockStore PersistentVolume: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, rancher

I have a 2 node K8S cluster deployed on EC2 instances. I used RKE to deploy the cluster (not kube-up), and I'm trying to use an AWS EB Volume as K8S Persistent volume. Created volume and instances are in the same region (us-east-2).

I configured k8s user to access aws through CLI and even exported specific AWS variables: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

When I try to create the PV ( `kubectl create -f aws-persistent-volume.yml` )I always get:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "aws-persistent-volume.yml": persistentvolumes "minio-volume" is forbidden: error querying AWS EBS volume vol-xxx: error finding instance i-xxx: "error listing AWS instances: \"NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated. \\n\\tFor verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors\""
```

My PV YML file is the following:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: minio-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    volumeID: vol-xxx
    fsType: ext4
```

Listing volumes (`aws --region us-east-2 ec2 describe-volumes --volume-id vol-xxx`) gives no problems:

```
{
    "Volumes": [
        {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2a",
            "Attachments": [],
            "Encrypted": false,
            "VolumeType": "gp2",
            "VolumeId": "vol-xxx",
            "State": "available",
            "Iops": 100,
            "SnapshotId": "",
            "CreateTime": "2018-04-23T14:17:22.563Z",
            "Size": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

Additional informations: OS Centos 7, Kubernetes v1.8.3

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The traditional way is to grant an IAM role to the EC2 instances that are running your Nodes, as is [described here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/1.9.0/docs/iam_roles.md) (yes, I know that's for Kops, but it was the quickest link I could find). If you "configured k8s user to access aws through CLI" using the k8s user's `.bashrc` or whatever, that's **not** the same as ensuring the kubernetes binaries (`apiserver`, `kubelet`, et al) have access to those env-vars

Comment: Hi @MatthewLDaniel thanks for your answer! Unfortunately without KOPS I found difficult to understand how to add an IAM role to my instances, do you think that [this procedure](https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/security/new-attach-an-aws-iam-role-to-an-existing-amazon-ec2-instance-by-using-the-aws-cli/?sc_channel=sm&sc_campaign=rolesforrunninginstances&sc_publisher=tw&sc_medium=social&sc_content=read-post&sc_country=global&sc_geo=global&sc_category=ec2&sc_outcome=launch) can be enough?

Comment: Yes, that sounds fine, or don't forget that Nodes are almost as disposable as Pods, so you can simple create a new one that does have an IAM instance-role

Comment: Separately, is there a great reason you're on such an ancient kubernetes version? There are innumerable bugs fixed between 1.8 and 1.10.2

Comment: Thanks @MatthewLDaniel. In you first comment are you saying that it's enough to add a single node with IAM roles configured? 
Regarding your second question the reason was just that in RKE example, K8s image was set with 1.8.3 version. I'll upgrade it ASAP. I'll let you know once I've configured "IAM node", in the meantime thanks a lot for the support!